# How do I import an Azure AD Service Principal Password into Terraform?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

We're using Terraform to build our cloud infrastructure. Previously we had a few service principals created without Terraform that are being used right now on production and can't be changed. Now we want to move to Terraform the creation of that service principals, but we're unable to import the previous ones while keeping a structure to create new ones using random_string.

```
resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "service-images" {
  for_each             = toset(var.profiles)
  service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.service-images[each.value].id
  end_date             = "2222-01-01T23:00:00Z"
  value                = random_string.images_password[each.value].result
}
resource "random_string" "images_password" {
  for_each = toset(var.profiles)
  length   = 32
  special  = true
}
```

When we create a new service principal (by adding an element to var.profiles list) it works fine, but when it's a already used service principal, we're worried that Terraform will smash the previous value and go down in production.

Also, Terraform seems to have an import interface for azuread_service_principal_password:

```
terraform import azuread_service_principal_password.test 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
```

Where first part is ServicePrincipalObjectId and second part is ServicePrincipalPasswordKeyId, however I can't find that latter value on Azure Portal (where is it?).

How would you proceed?

Comment: I'm not clear what you want. Do you mean just create a new password for the existing service principal?

Comment: I want to import/keep the passwords for my old profiles and also generate new passwords for new profiles, using the same codebase for old and new service principals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as I know the service principal can only have one password. So you cannot keep the password for the old profile and also generate a new password for the new profile.

I will recommend you use the application registry secret for the authentication. The secrets of the application registry associated with the service principal can also be used for the service principal, and the application registry can have multiple secrets. So you need to create the resource [`azuread_application_password`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/r/application_password.html) instead of the resource `azuread_service_principal_password`.

Here is an example:

```
data "azuread_application" "example" {
  name = "My First AzureAD Application"
}

resource "azuread_application_password" "example" {
  application_object_id = "${data.azuread_application.example.id}"
  value                 = "VT=uSgbTanZhyz@%nL9Hpd+Tfay_MRV#"
  end_date              = "2020-01-01T01:02:03Z"
}
```

Comment: You cannot pass the value. It is created later.